# "name 'Size' does not exist in the current scope" even though I've referenced it and it isn't highlighted?

Tags: typescript

## error message

> Compile Error. 
>   See error list for details
>    .../Scripts/gallery.ts(13,15): The name 'Size' does not exist in the current scope

### gallery.ts

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery.custom.js" />

(function ($) {
    var $body = $(document.body);
    var $win = $(window);
    var animTime = 1000;
    var $cg = $('#control_grid').data('flash', false);

    function fitImage(img, max, enlarge) {
        var ratio = Math.max(img.width / max.width, img.height / max.height);
        if (ratio < 1 && !enlarge) ratio = 1;
        return Size(Math.round(img.width / ratio), Math.round(img.height / ratio));
    }

    ...
```

### jquery.custom.js

```
function Size(w, h) {
    return {
        'width': w,
        'height': h
    };
}

...
```

### question

When I mouse over "Size" in `gallery.ts` in Visual Studio it pulls up the correct definition, so clearly it can find the function. Why is the TS compiler giving me this error then?

The `Size()` function is at root level in `jquery.custom.js`, it should have global scope, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get type information by referencing a JavaScript file. You could either write that function in TypeScript, or create a definition file for it, i.e. `jquery.custom.d.ts`.

Comment: Now sure why I never came back to this question, but I don't think the problem was "not getting type information" (as VS *did* give type info), but rather why it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Hi @Mark - it is still because you are referencing a JavaScript file :)

Comment: Fair enough. So there's no way to work with JS libraries without a `.d.ts` file or renaming them (which won't give type info without a rewrite)?

Comment: Not really - if the library is tight enough, simply pasting it into a `.ts` file will solve the entire problem - but most libraries contain either deliberately dynamic types or an impossible to infer structure. That's what Definitely Typed is for though... http://definitelytyped.org/